# How make a pixcel effect in android?

Tags: android, bitmap, effects

Like this photo: http://www.designerfreelance.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/pixel.jpg

It like a pixelize effect of Picsay app ( on Touch event will draw this effect).
 How can i do? or what is solution? note:without create new bitmap - i want it smoothly, use color matrix or something like that :) 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

As you can see on the picture, original image is blended with fully pixelized one. Pixelized image is basically sliced to squares and then each square is filled with its average color. This is easy to implement in code.
Doing it smoothly may be not easy on Android, but you can try placing a view with pixelized image over original and gradually increasing its opacity.